# Code conversion to ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary-operator

How can I convert the logic below to a ternary (`?:`) operator?

```
if (node.getLeftChild() == null)
    return 0;
else
    return node.getLeftChild().getValue();
```

Comment: `return (expression) ? (true-case-value) : (false-case-value);`

Comment: Searching for the solution would have helped you too! Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Point of information to help you in your searches on this... What you're looking for is an "operator" not a "function" and while it is *a* ternary operator (possibly even the only one in the language) it isn't *the* ternary operator (since there could be more).  It is the "conditional operator."

Answer (score 4):

```
return (node.getLeftChild() == null) ?  0 : node.getLeftChild().getValue();
```

`?:` is used as follows:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```